# Require SSH passphrase with each use

Tags: 14.04, unity, ssh

I regularly use Ubuntu's ssh command to connect to a server that I administrate (I even have a .desktop setup for it). I use a passphrased SSH key for authentication. I would like my computer to require the passphrase with each use rather than simply accepting it once per login as it does now. Specifically, once I type my passphrase into the dialog screenshotted below, it won't ask for it again if I open an addition SSH session (even after closing the first session) unless I first log out and log back in or restart.

I found plenty of information on how to enable behavior similar to this (ie. passphrase never asked for even after restart/relog) but barely anything relating to disabling it. The only thing I found about disabling it is [this](http://swoogan.blogspot.ca/2015/04/ssh-passphrase-chaos.html) -- which only applies to bits of Gnome invading/being pulled into KDE. This isn't relevant because I am using Unity.

Dialog (my computer's name is intentionally edited out of the screenshot):

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L297X.png) (I don't have enough reputation for embedded images)

Answer (score 0):

There is application called `seahorse` (I don't know why this name, but you can find it under "Passwords and keys" in your applications), which stores your passwords, `gpg` keys and also `ssh` keys and does basically the same as `ssh-agent` or `gnome-keyring`.

If you don't want your computer to remember the passphrase, just remove the key from the "OpenSSH keys" list and it should do the job.

Comment: I think the goal is to use certificate for authentication but not cache the passphrase. For this I would configure or disable ssh agent.

Comment: @Jakuje If I remove it from OpenSSH Keys, won't that prevent me from being able to use it without -i? I'd prefer to have the key properly installed so that it is automatically used.

Comment: @JackWasey I looked at the man page for ssh-agent. I didn't see anything regarding disabling password caching. Perhaps you could elaborate in an answer?

Comment: You don't need to use it with `-i`. If it is on its place (`~/.ssh/id_$TYPE`), it will be used automatically and if not, you can specify it in your configuration in `~/.ssh/config` as `IdentityFile` option.